# C++11 Kill threads when main() returns?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I heard that "a modern operating system will clean up all threads created by the process on closing it" but when I return `main()`, I'm getting these errors:

> 1) This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>     Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>
> 2) terminate called without an active exception

My implementation looks like this (I'm writing now for example sorry for bad implementation):

```
void process(int id)
{
    while(true) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1); } }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread thr1(process, 0);
    std::thread thr2(process, 1);
    //thr1.detach();
    //thr2.detach();
    return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment `detach();`s, there is no problem but my processing threads will be socket readers/writers and they will run infinitely (until main returns). So how to deal with it? What's wrong?

**EDIT:** Namely, I can't detach() every thread one-by-one because they will not be terminated normally (until the end). Oh and again, if I close my program from the DDOS window's X button, (*my simple solution not works in this case*) my detach(); functions being passed because program force-terminated and here is the error again :)

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want to exit the program or do you want to have it running forever?

Comment: @usr I just want to kill (**edit:** _terminate/detach_) all threads normally when `main()` returns.

Comment: Read the quote you heard again, and see how it says nothing about returning from `main`.

Comment: Please don't format quotations as code. In English we use quotation marks to demarcate quotations.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Oh, that's ok. I'm new in here, sorry about it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens in an application is not related to what the OS may do.

If a `std::thread` is destroyed, still having a joinable thread, the application calls `std::terminate` and that's what is showing up: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread`

With the c++11 threads, either you detach if you do not care on their completion time, or you care and need to join before the thread object is destroyed.

Comment: Maybe a simple solution example? **edit:** handle the destructor and kill/terminate the thread process yourself, right?

Comment: Simply store all your worker threads in a class that `join()` them in the destructor. Oh and, Boost.Asio seems to be the right tool for you (since you want to do a network application). You can easily setup a threadpool of network worker threads and exit gracefully.